# jquery Navigation animation show

Tags: jquery, animation, navigation, slide

I have created a jquery navigation that hides on scroll down and shows on scroll back up.

I'm having trouble executing the following;

1) hide after 500px scrolled down.

2) slide in and out smoothly exactly like this navigation https://www.wunderlist.com/en/

3) There also seems to be a small bug making it not always show on scroll back up.

Here is my demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/w2Xx7/

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
var scroll_time;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(scroll_time);
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (current_scroll >= $('#site-header').outerHeight()) {
        if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
            $('#site-header').removeClass('hidden');    
        }
        else {
            $('#site-header').addClass('hidden');  
        }
    }

    scroll_time = setTimeout(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    }, 100);
});
```

Thanks a bunch everyone !

Comment: your `setTimeout()` function is executed just once, 100ms after the other js code. So in line `if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos)` will always be false if you are not in the top of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your help. could you demonstrate what you mean using jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
var scroll_time;

$(window).scroll(function() {
clearTimeout(scroll_time);
var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (current_scroll >= $('#site-header').outerHeight()) {
    if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
        $('#site-header').animate({top:'0'});    
    }
    else {
        $('#site-header').animate({top:-52});  
    }
}

scroll_time = setTimeout(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    }, 100);
});
```

or simple, working version:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $("#site-header").offset();

    if (position.top <= 200) {
       $('#site-header').animate({top:0}, 100);    
    } else {
       $('#site-header').animate({top:-52},100);  
    }
});
```

top scroll version:

```
var prev_pos = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var position = $("#site-header").offset();
    var current_pos = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (position.top >= 200 && current_pos > prev_pos) {
       $('#site-header').animate({top:-52}, 100);
    } else {
       $('#site-header').animate({top:0}, 100);    
    }
    prev_pos = current_pos;
});
```

Comment: Hi, this is great thank you. Is it possible to make the navigation show as soon as you scroll back up to???

Comment: Have a look at 3rd version. Navigation shows as soon as scroll back up. 100 is animation time, so you can change it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var scroll_pos = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {

var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();

if (current_scroll >= $('#site-header').outerHeight()) {
    if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
        $('#site-header').removeClass('hidden');    
    }
    else {
        $('#site-header').addClass('hidden');  
    }
}

});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, but this doesnt seem to work? can you use jsfiddle to show example?

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working? :s I want to create the exact effect like this nav https://www.wunderlist.com/en/